# Mysqli_error() does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following code:

```
  $dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","magnificantDatabase")
  or die("Could not connect to database");

  $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts(username, password, ip)
  VALUES('$username','$password','$ip')";

  mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)
  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Should return an error when the mysqli_query fails return an error, shouldn't it?
It doesn't though :/
Anyone have any ideas why it doesn't?

Oh and, by returning no error I mean it returns nothing at all.
just completely blank.

Edit: I'd like to let you know that after having searched the web (even though as this would seem a common problem) I have -NOT- found anything that fixes this, there are issues close to this one, but none of them I have found appear to be the exact same.

Comment: When I'm using just mysql it returns errors, or is the error reporting not shared? if it isn't where do I find this file on linux?

Comment: You can turn on `error_reporting` locally (see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)). Are you sure that you have `mysqli_` installed?

Comment: Just tried error_reporting(); and error_reporting(E_ALL); and yes, MYSQLI_ is installed correctly.

This is what phpMyAdmin Says about my PHP:
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.31
PHP extension: mysqli

Comment: try this `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: ini_set has fixed the problem completely, thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: @echo_Me that *really* should be an answer. Buried as a comment.. it took me forever to find and it immediately solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened to me when I executed an UPDATE statement.

mysqli_error, mysqli_errno and mysqli_error_list were all empty.

Then I discovered that the problem was that the database user assigned to the connection object did not have the UPDATE privilege.  I don't know why I did not receive an error message or an error number for this security/privilege breach.

Answer (score -2):

Try to this..

```
$dbnm = "magnificantDatabase";

$abc= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ("could not connect to mysql");     
mysqli_select_db($abc,$dbnm) or die ("no database");

$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts(username, password, ip) VALUES('$username','$password','$ip')";

mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: i think this answer is trying to suggest to use a connection link id -- $link = mysqli_connect( $host , $user, $pass ); mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysqli_error( $link ) ), -- because that is exactly what fixed this empty error response for me