# PDO with INSERT INTO through prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

On my adventure through the jungles of PHP: Data Objects I've encountered a problem with executing MySQL queries through prepared statements.

Observe the following code:

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "pdo";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "845625";

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname","$dbusername","$dbpassword");

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age)
        VALUES('Bob','Desaunois','18')");

    $statement->execute();
```

This is me, and I want to be in my database.
However I keep getting lost in.. well.. I don't know!
According to google this is the way to do it, though my database stays empty.

Am I missing something here? Because I've been stuck for a good hour now and would like to continue studying PDO!

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario this is likely an error reporting matter. Bob, are you familiar with error reporting in PHP? Are you able to see an error if occurred?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You should be using it like so

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'pdo';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = '845625';

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO testtable (name, lastname, age)
    VALUES (:fname, :sname, :age)');

$statement->execute([
    'fname' => 'Bob',
    'sname' => 'Desaunois',
    'age' => '18',
]);
```

Prepared statements are used to sanitize your input, and to do that you can use `:foo` *without* any single quotes within the SQL to *bind* variables, and then in the `execute()` function you pass in an associative array of the variables you defined in the SQL statement.

You may also use `?` instead of `:foo` and then pass in an array of just the values to input like so;

```
$statement = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO testtable (name, lastname, age)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

$statement->execute(['Bob', 'Desaunois', '18']);
```

Both ways have their advantages and disadvantages. I personally prefer to bind the parameter names as it's easier for me to read.

Comment: Is this also a "good" way to do this?

    $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age)
                    VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
                $statement->execute(array($this->name, $this->lastname, $this->age));

Comment: Yep, that's a good way to do it.

Comment: I just tried BOTH methods, the one with the question marks earlier because I stumbled upon it, both were to no avail.

I'm starting to worry the error is somewhere else, I will try to rewrite what I have now.

Comment: try adding `$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` directly after the `$link = new PDO...` line

Comment: Would you please remove quotes from around variables in connection code?

Comment: Removing quotes did not work, and the errormode code line didn't do anything, I'm now rewriting to make -SURE- there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Edited: added try/catch code and removed quotes in connection code as per @YourCommonSense's correction

Comment: -1 for adding try catch.

Comment: How else are errors in the query caught if you don't?

Comment: you don't need to catch this one. Most of time errors have to be reported, not caught. And PHP already excellent with it, no your help required. Catching has **absolutely different** purpose.

Comment: @YourCommonSense PHP documentation explicitly instructs developers to catch database connection errors in production code because the default error action is to display a backtrace that reveals database connection details.  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php.  -1

Comment: @vlasits it's a pity but that page is a complete bullshit. [There is no such "default action" in PHP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#reporting_errors).

Comment: Fun trick: if you don't want to hard code the column names, you can `$parsed = json_decode($myJson, true); $fields=array_keys($order); $fieldlist=implode(',',$fields); $valuelist=':'.implode(', :',$fields); $sql="INSERT INTO `orders`($fieldlist) VALUES ($valuelist)";`

Answer (score 5):

I have just rewritten the code to the following:

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "pdo";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "845625";

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age)
        VALUES(?,?,?)");

    $statement->execute(array("Bob","Desaunois",18));
```

And it seems to work now.
BUT. if I on purpose cause an error to occur, it does not say there is any.
The code works, but still; should I encounter more errors, I will not know why.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: Hm. It looks like [you knew it already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560144/mysqli-error-does-not-work#comment25546310_17560277) but for some reason still don't use.

Comment: I honestly completely forgot about init_set();
My sincere apologies.

Comment: Hard-Coding the inserted Values in there and also not explaining why you are using PDO and what you did is really not going to help the thread creator.

Answer (score -1):

Please add try catch also in your code so that you can be sure that there in no exception.

```
try {
    $hostname = "servername";
    $dbname = "dbname";
    $username = "username";
    $pw = "password";
    $pdo = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: One can be sure even without catch. Uncaught exception produces a fatal error, you know.

Comment: I don't know about uncaught exception produces a fatal error....if you have any link please share with me...for the pdo I have read it from here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: I can't find any fatal error....if you have any example please explain?

Comment: You need to enable error reporting in PHP and cause exception to throw.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for all your valuable information. I will definitely try it in my spare time.. :)

Comment: Always glad to help. Feel free to ask more.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to Novocaine88's answer to use a try catch loop I have successfully received an error message when I caused one.

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "pdo";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "845625";

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try {
        $statement = $link->prepare("INERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age)
            VALUES(?,?,?)");

        $statement->execute(array("Bob","Desaunois",18));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

In the following code instead of INSERT INTO it says INERT.

this is the error I got.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INERT INTO testtable(name, lastname, age) VALUES('Bob','Desaunoi' at line 1

When I "fix" the issue, it works as it should.
Thanks alot everyone!

Comment: Don't you think there are a bit too much answers to this question?

Comment: Not to mention this is a wrong one

Comment: I'm sorry to see that the amount of answers have made a mess of this issue, however instead of acknowledging that the answer is invalid I would very much like you to elaborate why this is a wrong answer.

Comment: because you should use ini_set(); instead of a "try catch loop"