# Insert a value (which you don't type but is echo'ed) into database through php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a car mileage and car color into a database, on the same page I am displaying that cars ID and the cars owner.

So I have two input fields where the user types the mileage and color and beneath that I am just displaying that cars ID and the cars owner.

The insert works fine, I can insert the mileage and color but it leaves two columns where the cars ID and cars owner (which are displayed on the page where I enter mileage/color) should be...

Does anyone know of a way to put them into the DB too as im not actually typing them, simply echoing them there. Code is shown below, thanks.

```
    Mileage:<input type="text" name="mileage"><br />
    Color:<input type="text" name="Color"><br />
    carID:<?php echo $cID; ?>
    carOwner: <?php echo $cOwner; ?>
```

The insert page is just a simple sql statement which only has the mileage/color values . I have tried adding carID and carOwner as extras but it throws errors.......any ideas?

Comment: put the values in hidden form inputs then they will be available to add do the db the same way as the filled in form inputs

Comment: how would i do that? could you please elaborate, i'm new to this

Comment: Wait, you want to insert the values they enter to a DB?

Comment: @Shahar that already goes in, the values displayed i want to insert to a DB

Comment: @user3334417 Then just make the input hidden. Or use AJAX with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Crude but easiest method and will match the style of the other data:

Show the carID and carOwner but prevent them from being edited:

```
Mileage:<input type="text" name="mileage"><br />
Color:<input type="text" name="Color"><br />
carID:<input type="text" name="cID" value="<?php echo $cID; ?>" readonly="readonly"><br />
carOwner:<input type="text" name="cOwner" value="<?php echo $cOwner; ?>" readonly="readonly"><br />
```

Forgot to add, the data will be posted just the same as "mileage" or "Color" for you to process however you like.

Comment: that is still displaying a textbox, i forgot to mention the $cID and $cOwner is coming from a PHP statement above and outside this form...

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make Your input type hidden:

```
Mileage:<input type="text" name="mileage"><br />
Color:<input type="text" name="Color"><br />
carID:<?php echo $cID; ?><input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $cID; ?>" /><br />
carOwner: <?php echo $cOwner; ?><input type="hidden" name="cowner" value="<?php echo $cOwner; ?>" /><br />
```

You should both echo `$cID` and `$cOwner` and include them as hidden values.
Then on the page where You've sent this form You can get the values `cid` and `cowner` the same as `mileage`, `Color` to insert into the database.
For post and get methods this would be respectively:

```
$_POST['mileage']
$_POST['Color']
$_POST['cid']
$_POST['cowner']
```

or

```
$_GET['mileage']
$_GET['Color']
$_GET['cid']
$_GET['cowner']
```

Here is a **not so safe** way to insert those values into the database:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name1,column_name2,column_name3,column_name4) VALUES (`$_POST['mileage']`,$_POST`['Color']`,`$_POST['cid']`,`$_POST['cowner']`);
```

The safer way would be to use:

```
$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (...fields...) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$st->execute($values);
```

where $values is an array of values You want to insert.

You can form the `$values` array from `$_POST` like that:

```
$values[] = $_POST['mileage'];
$values[] = $_POST['Color'];
...
```

Reference:
[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/pdo.prepare), [PDO with INSERT INTO through prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18655706/2510628).

Not so bad tutorial is located [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059). It will help You to get the idea, but it has some little errors, that are fixed in the comments of that post.

Comment: If You feel that some of the answers provided has helped you, please, be so kind to mark one of them as accepted.

Comment: If You'll stuck next at some point with the development of Your script, it is better to ask that as the new different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hidden inputs. They act just like a normal input tag but the user never sees them.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cID" value="<?php echo $cID; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cOwner" value="<?php echo $cOwner; ?>">
Mileage:<input type="text" name="mileage"><br />
Color:<input type="text" name="Color"><br />
carID:<?php echo $cID; ?>
carOwner: <?php echo $cOwner; ?>
```

Now you will receive 4 fields in your $_POST or $_GET whichever you are using

```
$_POST['cID']
$_POST['cOwner']
$_POST['mileage']
$_POST['Color']
```