# PDO INSERT INTO not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert a new record into a MySQL Db, but the prepared statement method I'm using isn't working. I'm using the query that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655706/pdo-with-insert-into-through-prepared-statements), and it looks like it should work perfectly but it doesn't. I'm getting no errors.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="registration" action="su-sql.php" method="post">  
    <ul>  

        <fieldset>
            <li><label for="email">Email</label></li>  
            <li><input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" onblur="checkEmail(this.value);" onchange="checkEmail(this.value);"/></li>  
            <li><label for="password">Password</label></li>
            <li><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required" aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" onblur="checkPassword(this.value);" onchange="checkPassword(this.value);"/></li>  
            <li><label for="passconfirm">Confirm Password</label></li>
            <li><input type="password" name="passconfirm" id="passconfirm" required="required" aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" onblur="checkPassconfirm(this.value);" onchange="checkPassconfirm(this.value);"/></li>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <li><label for="firstname">First Name</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required="required" aria-required="true" onblur="checkFirstname(this.value);" onchange="checkFirstname(this.value);"/></li>
            <li><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" required="required" aria-required="true" onblur="checkLastname(this.value);" onchange="checkLastname(this.value);"/></li>
            <li><label for="country">Country</label></li>
            <li>
                <select name="country" id="country" required="required" aria-required="true" onblur="checkCountry(this.value);" onchange="checkCountry(this.value);">
                    <option selected value="" class="option" id="choose">Choose your Country</option>

                    <?php

                    $countries = array('Afghanistan','Akrotiri','Albania','Algeria','American Samoa','Andorra','Angola','Anguilla','Antarctica','Antigua and Barbuda',
                        'Argentina','Armenia','Aruba','Ashmore and Cartier Islands','Australia','Austria','Azerbaijan','Bahamas, The','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Barbados',
                        'Bassas da India','Belarus','Belgium','Belize','Benin','Bermuda','Bhutan','Bolivia','Bosnia and Herzegovina','Botswana','Bouvet Island','Brazil',
                        'British Indian Ocean Territory','British Virgin Islands','Brunei','Bulgaria','Burkina Faso','Burma','Burundi','Cambodia','Cameroon','Canada',
                        'Cape Verde','Cayman Islands','Central African Republic','Chad','Chile','China','Christmas Island','Clipperton Island','Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
                        'Colombia','Comoros','Congo, Democratic Republic of the','Congo, Republic of the','Cook Islands','Coral Sea Islands','Costa Rica','Cote d\'Ivoire',
                        'Croatia','Cuba','Cyprus','Czech Republic','Denmark','Dhekelia','Djibouti','Dominica','Dominican Republic','Ecuador','Egypt','El Salvador','Equatorial Guinea',
                        'Eritrea','Estonia','Ethiopia','Europa Island','Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)','Faroe Islands','Fiji','Finland','France','French Guiana',
                        'French Polynesia','French Southern and Antarctic Lands','Gabon','Gambia, The','Gaza Strip','Georgia','Germany','Ghana','Gibraltar','Glorioso Islands','Greece',
                        'Greenland','Grenada','Guadeloupe','Guam','Guatemala','Guernsey','Guinea','Guinea-Bissau','Guyana','Haiti','Heard Island and McDonald Islands',
                        'Holy See (Vatican City)','Honduras','Hong Kong','Hungary','Iceland','India','Indonesia','Iran','Iraq','Ireland','Isle of Man','Israel','Italy','Jamaica',
                        'Jan Mayen','Japan','Jersey','Jordan','Juan de Nova Island','Kazakhstan','Kenya','Kiribati','Korea, North','Korea, South','Kuwait','Kyrgyzstan',
                        'Laos','Latvia','Lebanon','Lesotho','Liberia','Libya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania','Luxembourg','Macau','Macedonia','Madagascar','Malawi','Malaysia',
                        'Maldives','Mali','Malta','Marshall Islands','Martinique','Mauritania','Mauritius','Mayotte','Mexico','Micronesia, Federated States of','Moldova',
                        'Monaco','Mongolia','Montserrat','Morocco','Mozambique','Namibia','Nauru','Navassa Island','Nepal','Netherlands','Netherlands Antilles','New Caledonia',
                        'New Zealand','Nicaragua','Niger','Nigeria','Niue','Norfolk Island','Northern Mariana Islands','Norway','Oman','Pakistan','Palau','Panama','Papua New Guinea',
                        'Paracel Islands','Paraguay','Peru','Philippines','Pitcairn Islands','Poland','Portugal','Puerto Rico','Qatar','Reunion','Romania','Russia','Rwanda',
                        'Saint Helena','Saint Kitts and Nevi','Saint Lucia','Saint Pierre and Miquelon','Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','Samoa','San Marino','Sao Tome and Principe',
                        'Saudi Arabia','Senegal','Serbia and Montenegro','Seychelles','Sierra Leone','Singapore','Slovakia','Slovenia','Solomon Islands','Somalia','South Africa',
                        'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands','Spain','Spratly Islands','Sri Lanka','Sudan','Suriname','Svalbard','Swaziland','Sweden','Switzerland','Syria',
                        'Taiwan','Tajikistan','Tanzania','Thailand','Timor-Leste','Togo','Tokelau','Tonga','Trinidad and Tobago','Tromelin Island','Tunisia','Turkey','Turkmenistan',
                        'Turks and Caicos Islands','Tuvalu','Uganda','Ukraine','United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','United States','Uruguay','Uzbekistan','Vanuatu','Venezuela',
                        'Vietnam','Virgin Islands','Wake Island','Wallis and Futuna','West Bank','Western Sahara','Yemen','Zambia','Zimbabwe');  

                    foreach ($countries as $country) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$country.'" class="option">'.$country.'</option>';
                    }  

                    ?>

                </select>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </li>         
            <li><label for="gender">Gender</label></li>
            <li>
                <input checked type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required="required" aria-required="true" onchange="checkGender(this.value);"> Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required="required" aria-required="true" onchange="checkGender(this.value);"> Female
            </li> 
            <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></li>      
        </fieldset>

    </ul>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

And here's the PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);



$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "pass";
$db_name = "name";


$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);


do {

    /*
        Generate random number between min and max
        min: 1000000000
        max: 2147483647
    */

    $uid = mt_rand(1000000001,2147483646);

    // make sure that uid isn't already being used

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `uid` = :uid");
    $query->bindValue(":uid", $uid);
    $query->execute();

    $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} while ($user['uid'] === $uid);




$fbid = null;
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];


echo $firstname.' '.$lastname.': '.$uid;


// Using prepared statements almost eliminates the possibility of SQL Injection.

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `members`(uid, fbid, email, password, firstname, lastname, country, gender) 
    VALUES(:uid, :fbid, :email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :country, :gender)");

$query->execute(array(
    "uid" => $uid,
    "fbid" => $fbid,
    "email" => $email,
    "password" => $password,
    "firstname" => $firstname,
    "lastname" => $lastname,
    "country" => $country,
    "gender" => $gender
));


// get the user's DB entry 

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `uid` = :uid");
$query->bindValue(":uid", $uid);
$query->execute();

// Retrieve the results from the database
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($user) {
    echo '<br/>'.$user['firstname'].' '.$user['lastname'].': '.$user['uid'];
} else {
    echo '<br/>No User';
}
```

When the page loads, it shows the user's first and last name and their newly generated ID number all on the first line. The second line says "No User".

Please don't mind that the password isn't protected. I'm just getting this rolling.

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: Hard to say not knowing what the HTML form looks like.

Comment: @Fred-ii- added the code for the HTML form

Comment: Well, all your form elements are named; that's good. I see JS associated with them, so if you're using Ajax, that could be another possible reason and that the values `{username:username}` may not match; hard to say. If all POST arrays echo out, then we can leave that out of the equation. Only other thing is to add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to see if it's a DB-related issue.

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii-, I didn't know about that error reporting. Adding that lead me to the answer.

Comment: You're welcome Justin; so what was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Fred-ii suggested, I added the following line after the db connection:

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

When I did this, I got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fbid' cannot be null' in /home/ourfilmclub/public_html/build/su-sql.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /home/ourfilmclub/public_html/build/su-sql.php(68): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/ourfilmclub/public_html/build/su-sql.php on line 68
```

Basically, the column `fbid` cannot be `null`. I replace `null` with `''` and now everything works wonderfully. Kudos @Fred-ii-

Comment: Ah.... strangely enough; the thought of the `null` did enter my mind earlier and was going to mention if your column could accept null values. Glad it got resolved, *cheers!*