# Regarding a Date Picker in php/javascript

Tags: javascript

**On add more click i am generating multiple date picker but its not working 
  please help me code is bellow**

Html Code

```
<input type="text" name="end_date[]" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker" required>  
<input type="text" name="start_date[]" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker1" required>
```

javascript code

```
$(function () { $("#datepicker").datepicker( {format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}); });
$(function () { $("#datepicker1").datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mention that you are creating dynamic text field so you have to use `.on` function:

Here is the solution:

```
$(function (){
   $('body').on('focus',"#datepicker", function(){
       $(this).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
   });​
   $('body').on('focus',"#datepicker1", function(){
       $(this).datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
   });​
});
```

Feel free to ask if you have any query.

Comment: echo $d_start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
   echo $d_end_date = $_POST['end_date'];for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($product_id); $i++)
$sql = "INSERT INTO cust_multi_order(custo_id,order_id,product_id,domain_name,billing_cycle,quenty,price,status,d_start_date,d_end_date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $q->execute(array($cust_id,$last_id,$product_id[$i],$domain_name[$i],$bill[$i],$qty[$i],$price[$i],$status,$d_start_date[$i],$d_end_date[$i]));
    }///it will give error array to string coversion

Comment: @nikichaudhari check the correct syntax of insert in pdo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655706/pdo-with-insert-into-through-prepared-statements

Comment: All filds will b multiply insrted only date will not inserted

Comment: try to print what is coming in variable `$d_end_dat‌​e`. use `print_r($d_end_dat‌​e)` to debug what is in this variable.

Comment: It will give array

Comment: I am post echo $row['d_end_date']; then it will give out put as array and if m inserting 2 records then first date will blank and 2nd date will inserted

Comment: try `print_r` instead of echo. write `print_r($row['d_end_date'])`

Comment: If i am printing print_r($d_end_date); then its given me properly out put but when i am insering that data into the database its goes only last data of array

Comment: @nikichaudhari can you show me what is the output of `print_r($d_end_date);`

Comment: Array ( [0] => 02/21/2017 [1] => 2017-02-27 ) Array ( [0] => 02/21/2017 [1] => 2017-02-22 ) this out put will come

Comment: You have different array each time so it is causing the issue.

Comment: ya , i'll convert that date in to the sql date format its work.. thanks for you guide.