# How to properly update a MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to update a row in a table using PHP, although I'm this is not my first time, but the update function is not working.

This is the php code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$server = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "dbpass";
$database = "dbname";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database, $con);

 $q=mysqli_query("UPDATE  `phonegap_login` SET  `firstname` =  'Alhia' WHERE  `reg_id` =50;");


if($q)
{
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "failed";
}
?>
```

And by the way, if you try INSERT into, it will work:

```
$q=mysql_query("insert into `phonegap_login` (`reg_date`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) values ('test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test')");
```

How do I fix it? the insert is working, updating a row is not.
I'm using a row with reg_id=50 for testing.

Comment: You're mixing mysqli_query and mysql_query. Only use mysqli_query. mysql_query is deprecated

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar Thank you! It worked, you can answer the question so I can mark your answer :D

Comment: This is subjective, so not putting it as an answer...but I recommend using PDO instead.  Examples of PDO online will also, typically, follow "best-practices" a bit better (such as named parameters), e.g.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655706/pdo-with-insert-into-through-prepared-statements

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar Thank you, I didn't know about mixing the query.

Comment: Take into account the comment of @KevinNelson it is better practice to use PDO

Comment: @KevinNelson yes thank you! I'll browse some examples and give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing mysqli_query and mysql_query. Only use mysqli_query. mysql_query is deprecated

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($database, $con);

$q=mysqli_query("UPDATE  `phonegap_login` SET  `firstname` =  'Alhia' WHERE  `reg_id` =50;");
```

Or, Object Oriented:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$q = $mysqli->query("UPDATE  `phonegap_login` SET  `firstname` =  'Alhia' WHERE  `reg_id` =50;");
```

Or, PDO:

```
$connectionString = 'mysql:host=' . $server . ';dbname='.$database;
try {
    $db = new PDO($connectionString, $user, $pass);
} catch ( PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database: (" . $e->getCode() . ") " . $e->getMessage();
}
$q = $db->query("UPDATE  `phonegap_login` SET  `firstname` =  'Alhia' WHERE  `reg_id` =50;");
```

Comment: One tip to avoid getting confused between `mysql_query` and `mysqli_query` is to always use the object-oriented interface: `$db->query(...)` will never accidentally use the obsolete interface for lack of an `i` character. It's also a lot less verbose and easier to read because of that.

Comment: So true. OOP is the way.