# Can't INSERT $_POST ARRAY to MySQL - JQuery DataTables Checkboxes by Gyrocode

Tags: php, mysql

I am aware that there have been a lot of questions on $_POST ARRAY and MySQL, and I've been through a lot of them. However, none of the ones I have looked at do the trick for me.

I am trying to pass the row id's from a JQuery DataTable (using Gyrocode's ckeckboes plugin), form submit.

If I use:-

```
$i = 0;
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $value){

        echo "value : ".$value. '<br/>';

        $i++;
    }
```

I get output of

value: 1
value: 25
value: 32
value: 5
value: 17

Which is what I would expect (the amount of lines and the number values depend on how many checkboes I check).

But when I put the query in, it won't save to the database:-

```
$i = 0;
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $value){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (rider_id, at_date) VALUES ('$value', NOW())";

        $i++;
    }
```

I have tried all kinds of variations of this but nothing I do seems to work and it seems like a dumb mistake I'm making :)

Thanks

Comment: You don't execute your SQL, without any idea of how your connection to the database is made it's difficult to know how to suggest you fix it.

Comment: I don't see where you're executing the query. The HTML/JS should probably be posted also. In either case, check for errors.

Comment: If your not sure - have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655706/pdo-with-insert-into-through-prepared-statements

Comment: Notice that executing this sql statement will make you vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. The js and HTML are the samples taken from [Gyrocode](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/). I know it's open to SQL injection attacks, but this is not for an open network, just something I am playing with.

I managed to get it working with the following PHP

```
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');

$rider_id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : [];

foreach($rider_id as $k=>$id) {

  $query = "INSERT INTO attendance (rider_id, at_date) VALUES ('{$id}', NOW())";

  $conn->query($query); 
}

header('location: index.php');
```

Just need to add some error handling.