# Registration/login form : No data is inserted in my DB

Tags: mysql, php-7.2

I'm trying to build a registration/login form using PHP (PHP 7.2.10), for now I'm just trying to be able to insert new users in my DB, and to log in with one of the users

```
<?php
//Connecion to the DB

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbtest; charset=utf8', 'root', '123456');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e;
}

//Registration form

//variables definition
if(isset($_POST['registration'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    $passwd2 = $_POST['passwd2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');

//checking mandatory fields are filled  
    if(!empty($nickname) AND !empty($email)){
        //checking entered email is valid
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            //confirming password
            if($passwd == $passwd2){
                // checking the entered email address doesnt already exist in the DB
                $TestEmail = $bdd->query('SELECT id FROM test WHERE email = "'.$email.'"');
                if($TestEmail->rowCount() < 1 ){
                    $bdd->query('
                        INSERT INTO test 
                            (name, first_name, sex, nickname, age, address, email, passwd) 
                        VALUES 
                            ("'.$name.'", "'.$first_name.'", "'.$sex.'", "'.$nickname.'", "'.$age.'", "'.$address.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$passwd.'", "'.$date.'")
                    ');
                } else $return = "There is already a user registered with this email address";
            } else $return = "Entered passwords are not matching";
        } else $return = "Please enter a valid email address";
    } else $return = "At least one field is missing";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Registration/Login form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(isset ($_POST['registration']) AND isset($return)) echo $return; ?>
    <!-- Registration/login form -->
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Name"><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "first_name" placeholder = "First Name"><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "nickname" placeholder = "Nickname"><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "age" placeholder = "Age"><br>
        <select name = "sex" placeholder = "Sex"><br>
            <option value = "Male">Male</option>
            <option value = "Female">Female</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type = "text" name = "address" placeholder = "Address"><br>
        <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Email address"><br>
        <input type = "password" name = "passwd" placeholder = "Your Password"><br>
        <input type = "password" name = "passwd2" placeholder = "Confirm your Password"><br>

        <input type="submit" name = "registration" value="Register">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <?php if(isset ($_POST['login']) AND isset($return)) echo $return; ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Email address"><br>
        <input type = "password" name = "mdp" placeholder = "Your Password"><br>

        <input type="submit" name = "login" value="Log in">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

- When trying to register a new user, I fill all the fields, then click on "register", but nothing happens, it just empties all the fields, and no data is inserted in my DB, though I get no error message.
- When trying to log in, I get the following error on top of my form : "Notice: Undefined index: passwd in C:\wamp64\www\Hakikar\index.php on line 61", and besides, the message "At least one field is missing", though I filled both email and password fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO with INSERT INTO through prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655706/pdo-with-insert-into-through-prepared-statements)

Comment: Your password field is named `mdp` so that’s why there’s no `passwd` in the post results. Also you open unnecessary database connections, are open to SQL Injection vulnerabilities etc.

Comment: OMG thanks a lot for the passwd field, I'm such an idiot ....

Comment: In the values you have date  but in the insert statement columns you haven't add column date possibly that's why you have no data inserted.

Comment: Stupid errors, indeed, shame on me ... Thanks a lot guys for your help!